# "Фото" — старое ударение

Tags: орфоэпия, сокращения

В фильме *"Не горюй"* Леван говорит:

> Клянусь прахом отца, после свадьбы возьму их в Тифлис и сделаю **фото́**.

*Скажите, он случайно так сказал или так говорили первое время после того, как стали сокращать слово "фотография"?* Фильм, кстати, 1968 года.

Там же ещё встречается ударение "автомо́биль". Так тоже раньше говорили?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Артём, не стоит искать правильного ударения у комедийных героев такого типа. Кто такой  Леван?  Сельский доктор, больше шарлатан, придумывает мудреные диагнозы, произносит якобы по-латыни названия несуществующих лекарств, он хочет произвести на пациентов впечатление ученого человека. Отсюда и  "фото́" (как авто́), и "автомо́биль" (от перпетуум мо́биле). Это просто речевая характеристика героя. Никакой научной подоплеки здесь нет.

Comment: Понятно) Спасибо, Людмила!

Comment: И всё-таки он хороший человек! Семье девочки послал продуктов и барана в придачу, например, а денег не взял.

Comment: Теоретически, могло на какое-то время (в фильме конец 19 века, фотография появилась в 40-х годах) быть непосредственно заимствовано французское сокращение слова photographie (**la photo**). Но и для грузинского органичны сокращения с ударением на последнем слоге (Автандил - Авто́, Иосиф - Сосо́ и т. п.). Сложно проверить, когда появилось _современное_ русское сокращение (у Даля его ещё нет). Альтернативное ударение в слове _автомобиль_ совпадает с итальянским вариантом l'automо́bile - возможно, это и случайно. Маловероятно, чтобы создатели фильма занимались такими изысканиями.